# Does magic find affect Tome of Secrets drops?

Tags: diablo-iii

Unlike the majority of crafting ingredients, the Tome of Secrets found in Inferno is considered a blue item. Does increasing magic find help increase the number of tomes found? Or are they treated like the other white text craft ingredients (pages/books)?

Comment: Based on Diablo 2 knowledge if Tome of Secrets is a magic version of Tome of bs/jc then more more MF should increase there drop chance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have proof, but in my experience in Inferno, I get more Tome of Secrets drops when i have 5 stacks of Nephalem's Valor, which gives +75% magic find.

Comment: If you have your experience. This is proof.

Comment: @MichelAyres Not really. Not unless you have made statistical calculations to verify your hypothesis. If it is just a gut feeling it not really proof...

Comment: I'll run some experiments soon and update my answer, as I'm actually quite curious - I think I can try clearing the first area out of the gate 10 times (never has an elite), then do the same after getting stacks in a later area.